# How to resolve ORA-00984 when using SQL in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to store a lsit of predefined Oracle database administrative user accounts to a table *DBOMIT_SCHEMAS* using a list *schema_list* as in code.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE schema_list_type IS TABLE OF "DBCONTROL"."DBSCHEMA_INFO".SCHEMA%TYPE;
  schema_list schema_list_type;
BEGIN
  schema_list := schema_list_type('ANONYMOUS', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS', 'OWBSYS', 'ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS', 'OUTLN', 'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'SYS', 'SYSMAN', 'SYSTEM', 'TSMSYS', 'WK_TEST', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY', 'WMSYS', 'XDB');

  FOR i IN schema_list.FIRST .. schema_list.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('***DEBUG***: '||schema_list(i));
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('INSERT INTO "DBCONTROL"."DBOMIT_SCHEMAS" VALUES('||schema_list(i)||')');
  END LOOP;

END;
```

When I'm trying to loop through the list and insert each value to the table, I get **ORA-00984: column not allowed here** error. I guess, this happens because it understands ANONYMOUS (column name) instead of 'ANONYMOUS' (String). Could anyone please  resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kodiko is right, you don't need dynamic SQL here at all, and shouldn't be using it (since there no need - harder to write, harder to debug, ...). But for your actual error, it's because you're using a hard-coded string value without enclosing it in quotes. You would need to use:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('INSERT INTO "DBCONTROL"."DBOMIT_SCHEMAS" VALUES('''
  ||schema_list(i)||''')');
```

That changes the end of the executed SQL from `VALUES(ANONYMOUS)` to `VALUES('ANONYMOUS')`. The extra quotes are doubled-up as they need to be escaped, and that is the mechanism. (You can use the alternative quoted syntax but when building up a string I find that less obviously useful).

But you shouldn't be hard-coding the value at all, you should be using a bind variable:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('INSERT INTO "DBCONTROL"."DBOMIT_SCHEMAS" VALUES(:id)')
USING schema_list(i);
```

Well, in this case, you should be using plain SQL, but if you do have to use dynamic SQL then you should use bind variables.

I'd also lose the double-quotes around the schema and table names as they don't need to be quoted, so they're really just noise. You could also use `forall` to do a batch insert, and if the `type` was declared at schema level then you could do this in a single insert without the loop, but I guess this is an exercise.

Comment: When I use plain SQL statement, I get **ORA-06550:** error. This is because I have an **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** statement to create the table before inserting values. I tried separating them, and it worked fine. And even when I use bind variable, I get **ORA-00911: invalid character** error. It works as I needed with extra quotes.

Comment: @Syam - yes, if you're creating the table dynamically you're right, the insert does have to be dynamic too. (Creating tables on the fly is unusual though). You don't need quotes around the bind variable; but it would really have helped if I'd used the Oracle `:var` syntax instead of the JDBC `?` syntax. If you just put quotes around that then all the values inserted in your table will literally be `'?'`, not the actual schema names. I've corrected (and tested) that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need execute immediate here, just do:

```
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('***DEBUG***: '||schema_list(i));
    INSERT INTO "DBCONTROL"."DBOMIT_SCHEMAS" VALUES(schema_list(i));
  END LOOP;
```